# libreria JWT DECODE

Tags: javascript

Buenos días. Tengo un problema con la librería JWT DECODE, resulta que la estoy utilizando para poder decodificar el token que me envía una API para el ingreso en mi login. Cuando la utilizo en mi servidor local funciona perfectamente, pero ahora que tengo mi proyecto en el servidor de pruebas me genera estos errores cuando cargo la vista del login:

login.html:54 GET http://test.biccofarms.com/controlingresofe/node_modules/jwt-decode/build/jwt-decode.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED

login.html:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://test.biccofarms.com/controlingresofe/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0

login.html:1 This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see https:

login.html:54 GET http://test.biccofarms.com/controlingresofe/node_modules/jwt-decode/build/jwt-decode.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Y estos errores cuando ingreso el usuario y la contraseña:

[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check

VM153:1 GET http://test.biccofarms.com/controlingresoapi/?token=Bearer%20eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmFtZSI6IkFkbWluaXN0cmFkb3IiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiIxIiwidGVuYW50SWQiOiIxIiwidGVuYW50TmFtZSI6IkJpY2NvIEZhcm1zIFMuQS5TIiwiZW1haWwiOiJiaWNjb2ZAYmljY29mYXJtcy5jb20iLCJyb2xJZCI6IjEiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTM4NzY5MjQsImV4cCI6MTUxMzg3NzUyNCwidHlwZSI6ImltcGxpY2l0In0.WOZnvmunh6hkf7YZMZE0UvpKuUk3nkskCag9phIxDHg 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught ReferenceError: jwt_decode is not defined
    at Object. (capturelogin.js:53)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

y pues la verdad no entiendo porque. Mi duda es saber si esta librería solo funciona en servidores locales o porque me esta generando estos errores en el servidor de prueba.

Les agradecería me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: 1. Activa CORS en el servidor. 2. Usa de preferencia la [librería oficial](http://npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) de Auth0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muy poca información y a la vez demasiada para darte una respuesta concreta. Tienes dos errores fundamentales.

El primero, `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest ...`, indica que a partir de la última versión de jQuery se ha prohibido el uso de XMLHttpRequest síncrona (ésta se usa en las llamadas a `ajax` con `async:false`). No he encontrado nada por `jwt-decode` al respecto, así que es posible que sea en tu propio código (concretamente en `capturelogin.js:16`), pero no puedo asegurarlo.

El segundo señala que estás haciendo una llamada a `localhost` desde el servidor remoto, algo que sólo puedes autorizar explícitamente configurando el CORS. Sin embargo, dudo que sea lo que pretendías, es más probable que en algún lugar de la configuración tengas indicado `localhost` como servidor para la api.

Comment: muchas gracias @delCano, la verdad estoy muy confundida